# Determining/calculating Big O notation

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

So, I understand that Big O is essentially the time coplexity of a function/algorithm, however my textbook was so brief on the matter, it is difficult to resolves seemingly simple questions like this.

> Determine big O notation for function `f(n) = 1000n + 0.1n^2 + n ln ⁡x`

My attempt/guess is `O(n^2(n Ln x))`, but wouldn't the x be considered a constant and therefor omitted?
What is the best way to solve questions of this type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you have the entire Internet at your disposal, any shortcomings of your textbook can be easily compensated.

Comment: It seems there are [a](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834881/how-do-i-find-big-o-notation-for-this-function) lot [of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461281/finding-the-big-o-of-a-function) similar [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100315/finding-big-o-of-a-function) on math.stackexchange.com. Have you tried to figure out your problem from looking at those examples?

Comment: For that function, in order to determine complexity in O notation,  you must take term with highest power. So, in this case, the complexity is obviously O(n^2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right answer is `O(n^2)`.

See, you have a sum `f(n) = a(n) + b(n) + c(n)` and the only thing that matters is the "largest" (quickest growing) summand. Let's compare:

- `1000n` is linear in `n`
- `0.1n^2` is <s>cubic</s> quadratic in `n`
- `n ln(x)` is linear in `n` (whatever `x` is, `f` doesn't depend on it, so `ln(x)` is as constant as `42` or any other fixed quantity)

What's the largest one? Right - the <s>cubic</s> quadratic term `n^2`, hence the answer: "`f(n)`  is in `O(n^2)`".